# Project Properties Tab string Value is missing spaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In my project settings, I have the following string value: "Tracking Service". The white space in the string is important because I use it to access a Windows Service. When I look at the config file after installing my application on a PC, the string value is missing the white space. Looking at my debug folder, the string value is also missing the space in the .config file.

Is there way to perserve the white space from the Settings Tab in my project properties? I plan to install this application on multiple PCs and I would perfer for the string to keep it's actual value then having to go in and modify each config file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure what to say, I've never had a problem with spaces in settings values. Did you perhaps mean settings *key* (in which case I'm not sure what you're really trying to do)?

Comment: I am storing a service name in the the settings file of my project. The service name has a space in it. In my code, I pull out the service name from Properties.Settings.Default to create a Service Controller. For some reason, when I pull out the string the service string is missing the space. I see this after installing my application on Windows 2008 server.

Comment: Again I'm not sure what to say. I just set a settings value in the project properties, `test = "test value with spaces"`, and referenced it with `Properties.Settings.Default.test` with no issue. How are you installing the application? Could there be a faulty default embedded config file that's getting deployed?

Comment: Hi lc, you were correct. I had renamed the project and had a reference to an old config file which was I believe was causing conflicts. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad you found your problem :). Feel free to add your own answer below and accept it once the system lets you in a couple of days. It might help the next person that comes along.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform it to and from your settings.

split:

```
string [] VariableName.Split(new [] {'_'});
```

Join:

```
string remerged_Variable= string.Join(" ", splitParts);
```

Will this do for your purpose?